# How to solve this equation? $|x-5|=10$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve the following equation? $$|x-5|=10$$

Many thanks!

Comment: Hint: $|x|=y$ if and only if $x=y$ or $x=-y$.

Comment: Very glee title.

Answer (score 5):

Surely, you must revise absolute value equations. (You can start  **[here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/solving-linear-equations-and-inequalities/absolute-value-equations/v/absolute-value-equations)**.)

Anyway, as regards this particular equation, you get:

$(x-5)=10$, if $x>5$

or

$-(x-5) = 10$, if $x<5$

Solutions: $x= -5$ or $x= +15$

(From Wolfram Alpha) **Plot**:

[image]

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Dear Nick: I used the tool bar to insert the hyperlink as an embedded link in the text. Hope you don't mind!

Comment: @Nick I think you have an error, it should be $x=-5$ or $x=15$.

Comment: @Adobe Yup. That was a typo.

Comment: @amWhy Yep, it looks better now.

Comment: @Nick Your link to KhanAcademy is broken, i.e. it doesn't work: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/solving-linear-equations-and-inequalities/absolute-value-equations/v/absolute-value-equations%29 Here is the correct link: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/solving-linear-equations-and-inequalities/absolute-value-equations/v/absolute-value-equations

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that we are talking about the usual absolute value on the reals,
the more general approach to me would be (for $z \geq 0$)

$|x|=z \Leftrightarrow |x|^2 = z^2 \Leftrightarrow x^2 = z^2$

Now in your case take $x := x-5$, $z:= 10$.

Comment: Why complicate things? We can easily solve it without having to square both sides.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$|X|=X\quad\text{ or }\quad|X|=-X$$

Comment: @JohnnyWesterling This is true. $|x-5|=x-5$ or $|x-5|=-(x-5)$ It is somewhat similar to what *Stefan* said.

Comment: OK, perhaps you're right, but it's true only for an $X$ that changes it's sign (for example, a linear function), isn't it? Then the task is to determine for which $x$ which one holds.

Comment: @JohnnyWesterling I don't understand what you mean. Here is how to proceed: $$|x-5|=10 \begin{cases}|x-5|=x-5 & x-5=10\iff x=15 \\ |x-5|=5-x & 5-x=10\iff x=-5\end{cases}$$

Comment: OK, what you wrote in the hint is the very definition of absolute value, but it lacks the conditions on $X$, i.e. if $X>0$, then $|X|=X$ and if $X<0$, then $|X|=-X$. Without them the definition is incomplete and may be misleading, i.e. it may make one believe that, for example, $|10|=-10$, which is nonsense. It may be obvious to you, but it doesn't have to be to the OP.

Comment: @JohnnyWesterling No, I take the definition of the absolute value and reverse it since $x-5$ may be positive or negative. In your example we know for sure that $10$ is positive, but in the question the OP asks about we don't know that. That's why I wrote two cases.

Answer (score 1):

Just read the equation out loud: “The distance from $x$ to $5$ equals $10$.” Obviously there are two solutions.

Answer (score 1):

$|x-5|=10 \implies x-5=\pm10 \implies x=5\pm 10 \implies x=15$, or, $ x=-5.$